# Read environment.ts data from postbuild script

Tags: angular, typescript, sentry

Im configuring a postbuild script, in order to upload sourcemaps to sentry, like this:

```
const SentryCli = require('@sentry/cli');

async function createReleaseAndUpload() {
  process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN = 'MY_TOKEN';
  process.env.SENTRY_ORG = 'ORG_NAME'; 

  const release = process.env.release_version;
  if (!release) {
      console.log(process.env)
    //console.warn('release_version is not set');

    return;
  }

  const cli = new SentryCli();

  try {
    console.log('Creating sentry release ' + release);
    await cli.releases.new(release, ['MY_APP']);

    console.log('Uploading source maps');
    await cli.releases.uploadSourceMaps(release, {
      include: ['www'],
      // urlPrefix: '~/static/js',
      rewrite: false,
    });

    console.log('Finalizing release');
    await cli.releases.finalize(release);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Source maps uploading failed:', e);
  }
}

createReleaseAndUpload();
```

The problem I'm facing is that my release should come from the environment.ts file, and I do not know how to get/parse those values from the script (in the top) which is executed like this, in package.json:

```
 "postbuild": "node scripts/sentry.js"
```

Can anyone help me, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is ugly, I know, prone to errors, I know, but I got it working  like this:

```
function getEnvReleaseVersion(callback){

  lineReader.eachLine('./src/environments/environment.ts', function(line) {
    if(line.includes('release_version')){
      const splitted = line.split(':');
      if(splitted.length > 0){
        //trim 
        const result = splitted[1].replace(/\'/gi,'').replace(',','').replace(' ','');
        callback(result)
        return false;
      }else{
        callback()
        return;
      }
    }
  });
}
```